# LINQ - How do I compare the first two items in a group then the next?

Tags: c#, linq

I have two collections, A and B. Everything that goes into collection A should sum to 0 (these have unique identifiers that push them into Collection A) while Collection B doesn't have to sum to 0.  For example:

```
item1 = 200; 
item2 = -200; 
item3 = 200
```

These don't sum to 0 but have the same unique id's and are now in Collection A. I want to group them and compare the first two items and if they sum to 0, I move to the next items in the group and if those items don't sum to 0, I want to move them to collection B.

This is what I have now:

```
var grp= colA.AsEnumerable()
        .Where(a => a.Field<string>("unique_id") != null)
        .GroupBy(b=> b["unique_id"])
        .Where(c=> c.Count() > 1).ToList();
foreach(var d in grp)
{
  var sum = d.AsEnumerable().Sum(e => e.Field<decimal>("amount"));
}
if(sum != 0){//compare rows in group}
```

This successfully groups the items that don't equal 0 but I'm stuck at how to compare item1 and item2 then item3 so that item3 can be moved to collection B and Collection A will then be summed to 0.

Comment: Instead of `.Count() > 1` you should use `.Skip(1).Any()`

Comment: Also for taking just a portion out of a group you can try with `.Skip()` and `.Take()`.

Answer (score 1):

Would something like this help you?

```
grp.ForEach(g => 
{
    int stepNumber = 0;
    int step = 2;
    var target = g.Skip(stepNumber * step).Take(step);

    if (target.Sum(x => x.Field<decimal>("amount")) != 0)
    {
        foreach (var item in target.Select(x => x))
        {
            colA.Rows.Remove(item);
            colB.Rows.Add(item);
        }
    }

    stepNumber ++;
});
```

Comment: The statements `g.Skip(...).Take(...)` deliver a new `IEnumerable<>` object, but you don't use that new object. The statements do *not* modify `g` itself in any way, in case you were working from that expectation.

Comment: @PeterB D'oh! Thanks!

Comment: @pteberf Thanks for your help. I tried this and in the if statement, I have: `foreach(var row in target)
      {ColB.Rows.Add(new object[]
         {//add rows}
   } ` But all three items are still in CollectionA and nothing in Collection B.

Comment: @Love I'm not sure -- of what types are both collections?

Comment: @pteberf they are both DataTables

Comment: @pteberf Tried your edit but all three are still appearing in collection A. I'm trying to see if I'm seeing something. To clarify, I put this snippet of code in where I have `//compare rows in group.` in the question. So, this is in the if statement (if sum is not 0).

Comment: @Love well my whole answer was intended to replace the last five lines of the code in your question.

Comment: @pteberf I think there's something wrong with my if statement `(sum !=0 )`, I commented the codes in the if statement and did a `throw new systemexception` to test the if statement but it didn't work. So, that may be where the issue is. I'l work on that and get back to you on the update.

Comment: @Love, you don't need the whole `if (sum != 0)` statement thing after the loop. `target.Sum(x => x.Field<decimal>("amount")) != 0` already checks that.

Comment: @pteberf oh, okay. Will test that.

Comment: @pteberf I've edited but both collections are still the same. I'm not sure why this isn't working. The grouping should group those three together and remove the odd one out that doesn't make it sum to 0 but it's still in Collection A. I'll keep trying to see what the problem is. Thanks a lot.

Comment: @pteberf I tried a slightly different approach, though unusual but works for now. I use `var amt= item.AsEnumerable().Sum(c => (c.Field<decimal>("amount"));` And if the amount is 0 in the grouping, I take out those items and place in a different table and then remove the odd item. `foreach(var row in item)
    {//ab is a new table that matches ColA
     ab.Rows.Add(row.ItemArray);
     ColA.Rows.Remove(row);
     
    }` Now, all that's left in ColA is the odd one so that everything can sum up to 0 in the new collection. So I merge ColA and ColB to contain items that are not 0

Answer (score 0):

If you use Skip / Take to enumerate over your sequence, you'll start at the front of your sequence over and over again. This can be done smarter!

its a bit unclear what you want in the following sequence:

```
200, -200, 10, 11, -11, 12, -12, 13, -13
```

200 and -200 stay in collection A. But do you remove only 10, and let the pairs [11, -11], [12, -12], [13, -13] in A, or do your remove [10, 11], [-11, 12], [-12, 13], -13?

let's suppose you want the latter. You need to split your input sequence into pairs of two. For this, let's make a re-usable function.

Input: a sequence of items and a splitSize
Output: a sequence of ICollections where every ICollection has splitsize (except the last)

So input: 0 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 and SplitSize 3
Output: [0 1 2] [3 4 5] [6 7 8] [9]

I create this as an extension method, so you can use it in a LINQ concatenation. See [extension methods demystified](http://geekswithblogs.net/BlackRabbitCoder/archive/2013/03/08/c.net-little-wonders-extension-methods-demystified.aspx)

```
public static IEnumerable<IList<TSource>> Split<TSource>(this IEnumerable<TSource> source,
    int splitSize)
{
    // todo: check for non-null source and positive splitSize

    var enumerator = source.GetEnumerator();
    while (enumerator.MoveNext())
    {
       // still elements to process. Create and fill the next splitList
       List<TSource> splitList = new List<TSource>(splitSize);
       splitList.Add(enumerator.Current()
       while (splitList.Count < splitSize && enumerator.MoveNext())
       {
           // still elements to add:
           splitList.Add(enumerator.Current);
       }
       // if here: either no more elements, or splitList full.
       yield return splitList;
    }
}
```

With the help of this function we can split your input in pairs [0 1] [2 3] [4 5] and check whether they should be in the collection of zero-sum or non-zero-sum:

```
void CreateZeroSumCollections<TSource>(IEnumerable<TSource> source,
     Func<TSource, int> keySelector,
     out IList<TSource> zeroCollection,
     out IList<TSource> nonzeroCollection)
{
    var zeroCollection = new List<TSource>();
    var nonzeroCollection = new List<TSource>();

    var splitSource = source.Split(2);
    foreach (var splitElement in splitSource)
    {
        // the splitElement has a length of 2 or less
        // Check if the sum is zero
        if (splitElement.Count == 2 
            && keySelector(splitElement[0]) == -keySelector(splitElement[1])
        {   // 2 elements, and sum is zero
            zeroCollection.AddRange(splitElement);
        }
        else
        {   // either only 1 element or non zero sum
            nonzeroCollection.AddRange(splitElement);
        }
    }
}
```

For this your sequence has to be enumerated only once.

Comment: Thanks though I'm actually trying to achieve the former ( [11, -11], [12, -12], [13, -13] in A). I'm doing this so that everything in ColA sums up to 0

Comment: Sigh! Need to specify better. You wrote: "... if they sum to 0, I move to the next items in the group and if those items don't sum to 0, I want to move them to collection B" Thus: you said you want as a result two collections. My zeroCollection sums to zero, as specified